# What is the process to Edit/Change data in a row from a UITableView - Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

Can someone describe the process to edit/change the content from a row in a UITableView?

It looks like there is no enumerator for `edit`.

From the docs: [UITableViewCellEditingStyle](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcelleditingstyle)

Here is how I delete rows and update table.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        myArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        myTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
}
```

Comment: Follow this one i hope it would be helpful for you https://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views

Answer (score 1):

With the below code you can update any single cell of tableview

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: path, inSection: section)
tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Does the code needs to go inside the `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` method? I'm also a little confused as to where or how to update the data model array.

Comment: No, this code will be on that place where you want to make some changes in a cell of tableview, for example on click of any button of cell.

Comment: Hmm, I'm a little confused but let me play around and see if I can figure this out. Quick question, the update for the data model-array needs to happen between the `beginUpdates` method and the `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` method call, correct? Sorry but I'm not in-front of my computer at the moment.

Comment: Yes you need to update your data model then only call the above code, as the above code will call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and that will update you cell